# Is it possible to show 3d models using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, 3d, 3d-model

I can show vector layers from PostGIS using QGsMapCanvas and QGsVectorLayer in my standalone application. But now I need to show 3d models, for example 3dmax or sketchup, of some buildings over vector layers.

Is possible at all?

If it is possible, how can I do this?

Maybe there are any plugins for this?